# Contacts.app won't sync iCloud contacts

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, contacts

Just upgraded to macOS 10.12.16. For some reason my iCloud contacts are empty. Contacts.app does not show anything.

I tried signing out of iCloud, deleting AddressBook caches and files in `~/Library/Application Support` and then signing in again. Still, no Contact gets synced.

I can see all of my contacts via www.icloud.com and on my iPhone.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this issue for a couple of months and fixed it by doing the following:

- Quit Contacts.app
- Delete all content of `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook`
- Remove Contact sync from iCloud preferences in System Settings
- Wait couple of minutes, and re-enable Contacts sync
- Open Contacts.app and wait. Everything appears, and now Contacts syncs properly both ways.